# getting ebay india category list using Java API

Tags: java, ebay-api

I want to get ebay India category hierarchy or the list of categories with category id using Ebay API or any other way where they already provides the Category list. Please help me with where i can find a sample API call getAllCategories using Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the webservices of ebay.Here is the link.Try it and let me know.

http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/sdks/java

Comment: ok i got sample programs and i am trying . i will let you know the details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this [link](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetCategories.html) helps you. I am in PHP so don't know much about java, but in PHP i simply pass the XML feed given in the link above using required data and eBay API credentials into curl(). and it returns the data in XML format.